# Spring mvc bad request with @requestbody

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

i have a Spring MVC service with that signature:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/addUser", consumes = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody User addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
```

And this in context.xml

```
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I do a Post request and always return me a 400error->Bad request.
I write a filter to read the request content and is this:

Edit json:

```
{
    "email": "Anchor",
    "latitude": 40.3139461,
    "longitude": -3.8810229,
    "name": "a",
    "online": true,
    "password": "a",
    "deviceRegId": "APA91bGnD1EuqEm9cpoHsenC-HEphQJRniEnhPovK24QkKkLBXrDesSCP6CFlyOKwR1huwSI28Wd-DdN0N8MDKle7myYB7Dznzc3Z11ZOv3jMlJEIegykpnnnYScrElw2czQEa4pKFeQW7BklUsUS-IB15LMqH_Ag"
}
```

Edit: The user class

```
public class User implements Serializable{


@JsonProperty("deviceRegId")
private java.lang.String deviceRegistrationID;
@JsonProperty("email")
private java.lang.String email;
@JsonProperty("latitude")
private java.lang.Double latitude;
@JsonProperty("longitude")
private java.lang.Double longitude;
@JsonProperty("name")
private java.lang.String name;
@JsonProperty("online")
private java.lang.Boolean online;
@JsonProperty("password")
private java.lang.String password;

public User(String deviceRegid) {
    this.deviceRegistrationID = deviceRegid;
    this.online = true;
}

public java.lang.String getDeviceRegistrationID() {
    return deviceRegistrationID;
}

public java.lang.String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(java.lang.String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public java.lang.Double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(java.lang.Double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public java.lang.Double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(java.lang.Double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public java.lang.String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(java.lang.String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public java.lang.Boolean getOnline() {
    return online;
}

public void setOnline(java.lang.Boolean online) {
    this.online = online;
}

/**
 * @return value or {@code null} for none
 */
public java.lang.String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

/**
 * @param password
 *            password or {@code null} for none
 */
public void setPassword(java.lang.String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

Whats the problem?

Comment: Your user key is not quoted. This isn't valid JSON. And it's missing a closing curly brace as well. Use jsonlint.com

Comment: Can you share your request headers when calling the controller?

Comment: With quotes failed too.
Only send this header -> Content-type application/json

Comment: Please post your request

Comment: Im doing the request with a application software, in the raw body i writed the json

Comment: @colymore Share your User class.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Please remove the parametrized constructor and there you go. :)

```
public User(String deviceRegid) {
  this.deviceRegistrationID = deviceRegid;
  this.online = true;
}
```

Because at databinding default constructor is called.

Check your json data:

```
{
  "email": "Anchor",
  "latitude": 40.3139461,
  "longitude": -3.8810229,
  "name": "a",
  "online": true,
  "password": "a",
   "deviceRegId": "APA91bGnD1EuqEm9cpoHsenC-HEphQJRniEnhPovK24QkKkLBXrDesSCP6CFlyOKwR1huwSI28Wd-DdN0N8MDKle7myYB7Dznzc3Z11ZOv3jMlJEIegykpnnnYScrElw2czQEa4pKFeQW7BklUsUS-IB15LMqH_Ag"
}
```

Verify the following things:

1. Whether the **name** of JSON matches the User class's **field name**.
2. Also check whether JSON **value** is supported by the corresponding field name **datatype** in User class.

   Do try it, I have faced the same issue numerous times.

Comment: Because at databinding default constructor is called. We didn't I found this answer earlier. Hero!

Answer (score 0):

I was going to guess the problem is with `consumes = "application/json"`, and maybe it is... but I did a quick test adding that restriction to my environment (which is not specifying that it is sending `"application/json"`),

and instead I got a "415 Unsupported media Type".

Still, I recommend removing that and see if it helps.

Comment: Same result with and without it

Answer (score 0):

I had a bad request too. And sometimes bad syntax etc. But I fixed it with another Jackson Dependancy:

Instead of Codehause Jackson, I use now fasterxml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```