# Angular post not passing payload to java spring via long poll

Tags: java, spring, angularjs, long-polling

I am trying to pass variables using post in angular to java spring. The java post function is executed, but all of the parameters are null.

```
var CreditCard = $resource("http://:host::port/" + context + "/agent/creditCard",
{host: "localhost", port: 8080 }, 
   {getTestPost2: {method:'POST', params:{charge:true, jsonPost:"1234"}}
  });
var newCard = new CreditCard({number:'0123'});
newCard.name = "Mike Smith";
newCard.$save();
```

I checked the my network status shows 200 OK.

```
Request Payloadview source
{number:0123, name:Mike Smith}
name: "Mike Smith"
number: "0123"
```

Java

```
@RequestMapping(
            value="/agent/creditCard",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) 
    public @ResponseBody void getTestPost2( 
                    @PathVariable String clientId, 
                    @RequestParam(value="jsonPost", required=false) String jsonPost, 
                    @RequestParam(value="charge", required=false) boolean charge,               
                    @RequestParam(value="name", required=false) String name,
                    @RequestParam(value="number", required=false) String number
            ){

        logger.debug("jsonPost " + jsonPost);
        logger.debug("name " + name);
        logger.debug("charge " + charge);
        logger.debug("number " + number);

    }
```

Output:

```
jsonPost null
name null
charge false
number null
```

Comment: Although I am not familiar with Angular, I am willing to bet that your save method there is not posting form data, but something else (perhaps JSON), while the Spring Controller is clearly setup to accept form parameters

Answer (score 0):

Java

```
@RequestMapping(
            value="/agent/creditCard",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            params = { "jsonPost", "charge", "name", "number"}
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) 
@ResponseBody
    public @ResponseBody void getTestPost2( 
                    @PathVariable String clientId, 
                    @RequestParam(value="jsonPost", required=false) String jsonPost, 
                    @RequestParam(value="charge", required=false) boolean charge,               
                    @RequestParam(value="name", required=false) String name,
                    @RequestParam(value="number", required=false) String number
            ){

        logger.debug("jsonPost " + jsonPost);
        logger.debug("name " + name);
        logger.debug("charge " + charge);
        logger.debug("number " + number);

    }
```

I add params and ResponseBody, you can try it.

Comment: Hi @smallg, I tried your answer, but it doesn't work. The post call doesn't get execute and I'm getting a 400 header error.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a `CreditCard` class to use as the parameter type. Annotate it with `@RequestBody` to let a `HttpMessageConverter` convert the JSON body to the required object.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(
        value="/agent/creditCard",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) 
public void postCreditCard(@RequestBody CreditCard creditCard) {
    // process data...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Bart, I'll try this. I just searched for     'HttpMessageConverter', it seems I have to implement alot in Spring before I can see this call being executed.

Comment: That is not true. Just add Jackson 2+ to the classpath and a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` will be added automatically to the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`. It could not be any simpler.

Comment: Thanks @Bart, it works!. I also reference [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102697/spring-mvc-bad-request-with-requestbody).